# How to find whether a shared jsp file is accessed by more than one user?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a situation where there a link which takes values from the users and the link is shared to user. Multiple users can open the same link and if they try to fill the values they are getting overridden because of race conditions.

Can some body suggest a mechanism where if an user opens the link, and if another user tries to open the same link he should able to see some information that some body else is also viewing/modifying the content.

Comment: The problem is called duplicate form submission. Search for it :)

Answer (score 2):

This strategy is called pessimistic locking. It's generally not a good strategy, because you can't tell when the first user, which has locked the data, has finished editing it. He could have closed his browser, and never release the lock. You may of course use a timeout mechanism, but then you have to deal with the situation where the first user submits the modification after the timeout (if the timeout is short), or you forbid any user to edit the data for too long (if the timeout is long).

The usual way to deal with that is to use optimistic locking: you let everyone edit the data, but each time one submits, you check that the version number submitted (with a hidden field) is the same as the one in the stored data. If so, the edit is successful, and you increment the number. If not, then you tell the user that someone else has modified the data.

Comment: It should be possible to let a JavaScript ping the server with ajax calls to indicate that the user is still active on the page.

Comment: Even the browser is closed, we can reset the lock when the session gets timedout rt.

Comment: Even i like optimistic locking than pessimistic . Good idea.

Comment: optimistic locking is a nice idea. I will try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a Filter
- Have a application scoped synchronized map
- When there is a request coming set the some flag, when user is done editing you can reset that flag and if mean while another user comes based on the flag you can redirect her to another page

**Update :**

> if the first user opens the url, then i will update the synchronized map with some details. If the second users comes in then I will redirect him to some other page. Now if the first user does not commit the changes , then the second user will be blocked forever. Is there a way to avoid this ?

You can put *timestamp* when it was locked and release after particular time 
you also can make a  ajax poll so that if user1 has closed the editing/browser it will not poll so the map will say this is no longer in editing now

Comment: I have a question here, if the first user opens the url, then i will update the synchronized map with some details. If the second users comes in then I will redirect him to some other page. Now if the first user does not commit the changes , then the second user will be blocked forever. Is there a way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a flag in ServletContext saying the page is under editing.

1) when user access the shared page set the flag using `servletContext.setAttribute("linkEdited", "true")`. Also, set it inside the user session usign `session.setAttribute("linkEdited", "true")`.

2) unset the values when user commits the details entered `servletContext.setAttribute("linkEdited", null)` and `session.setAttribute("linkEdited", null)`.

3) also *unset (do step 2)* when the session gets timedout and the `session.getAttribute("linkEdited")` return true. When the session gets timedout the `HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed()` will be invoked.

4) When any user access the shared page check `session.getAttribute("linkEdited")` and `servletContext.getAttribute("linkEdited")`. If the attribute is set to true, give the message saying that the page is being edited.

Answer (score 0):

Have some id be part of the URL (as query param) that is being shared. When the 1st user clicks on the link, the id is passed on to the server and then you know user 1 is working on it. Now that id is active. When 2nd user clicks on it, the same id is sent to the server and you can now verify it against the currently active id's.

Answer (score 0):

You could store some information (e.g. in a shared map etc.) that the content is already being viewed.

I guess you don't want the information to be show if another user accesses the same JSP but with different data. Thus you should store information on the data that is being accessed, no the JSP itself. Then check whether that data has been access recently and whenever a user is finished remove the "being accessed" information (or reduce a counter).

If you want only one user to be able to concurrently edit the data, display the JSP in readonly mode whenever the data is already being accessed. If they *might* edit concurrently, you might want to use optimistic locking to handle updates in a FIFO manner.

A problem might still be sessions that are ended while the data is accessed. Thus you'd need some timeout to remove any dangling locks (much like a session timeout).